# Dashed line to fill instead of stroke

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, stroke, fill, path-effects

I am wanting to create a dashed line on the fill rather than the stroke if that is a possibility? I created outlines of a font and now I want to make it dashed. The left 'S' is what I am hoping to achieve, Its done badly but what I did is just overlay white rectangles on top of the path to imitate the dashed effect. Hoping to find an easier and more consistent way of doing this instead of individually moving the rectangles. The right 'D' is the adding a stroke to a path which is not want I want as I would like just one dashed line.

[image]

Comment: Make the characters a single path and use dashed strokes. Much easier than anything else.

Comment: Hi Wolff no I did't realise that sorry, I hardly come on here but will make note of that thanks